# How to do a WHERE query in Firebase using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to code this situation. Picture this structure:

```
Users
    ->john123
        -> name : john johnson
        -> clients:
            ->1: true
            ->2: true
            ->4: true
    ->thomasiscool
        -> name : thomas thomson
        -> clients
            ->3: true
Clients
    ->1
        ->info: ...
    ->2
        ->info: ...
    ->3
        ->info: ...
    ->4
        ->info: ...
```

I was reading the Firebase blog, but I can't seem to understand how to show, for example the clients for a specific user.
For example, john123 is logged in. He wants to see a table (ngrepeat) of his clients. It would show the client 1,2,and 4. 
How do I code this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I was thinking of using 2 references. ref1 = "firebase.com/clients" and ref2 = "firebase.com/users/user.id/clients". Then, use both to create like a bind or something to associate the childs of users with the clients childs.

Comment: See https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-10-01-queries-part-one.html. That is probably the blog you're referring to, in which case: please edit your question to include the link. Don't post code in a comment, just click the edit link under your original question and add it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. It looks a little complicated but once you understand the basics of Firebase it gets much easier. With this setup, it will dynamically update the list of clients as you add them into a user's profile. You can also take a look at the utility library [Firebase.Util](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-util) which would cut all this down to about 3 lines of code.

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwk1/ag1j11b3/3/)

Firebase URL: [Firebase](https://examples-jw1fns1hzxefypildty.firebaseio-demo.com/so1)

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($firebase, $scope, Client){

    $scope.allClients = Client.all;

    $scope.findClients = function(){
        $scope.clients = Client.findByRef($scope.name);
    }


});


app.factory('Client', function($firebase, $rootScope, $timeout){
    var ref = new Firebase($rootScope.demoUrl + '/clients');
    var clients = $firebase(ref).$asArray();

    var Client = {
        all: clients,

        findByRef: function(user){
            console.log(user);

            var indexRef = new Firebase($rootScope.demoUrl+ '/users/' + user + '/clients');
            var clientRef = new Firebase($rootScope.demoUrl+ '/clients');
            var tempClients = {};

            indexRef.on('child_added', function(ss1){
                var clientId = ss1.name();

                clientRef.child(clientId).on('value', function(ss2){
                    $timeout(function(){
                        tempClients[clientId] = ss2.val();
                    });
                })
            });
            return tempClients;

        }
    }

    return Client;
});
```

Comment: @Fabritzio Villegas Maybe too late but I forgot that the utility I used will create a new URL when different people view the fiddle, so it ends up with an empty Firebase. Fixed and fiddle works now. Sorry.